# nvd3, lineWithFocusChart for time series data is not displaying properly

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js

In my nvd3 lineWithFocusChart, y-axis data appearance is getting wired up. I have json data in correct format but still y-axis data is not appearing properly. I have put the reference plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/QwMbTL4co0wMVKaQurxq?p=preview.

I have even used tick format correctly but still the appearance is not proper. How to make this chart display the y-axis data correctly?

```
 tickFormat: function(d){
                        return  d3.time.format('%d/%m/%y')(
                                                new Date(d))
                    }
```

I have used below sorting function. But still it is not working.

```
angular.forEach($scope.data, function(series, index) {
                            series.values.sort(function(a, b) {
                                return a[0] - b[0];
                            });
                        });
```

Comment: From looking at the way the chart gets drawn, it seems like your time stamps are not sorted, could you double check on that. The problem is with your data.

Comment: I tried,  angular.forEach($scope.data, function(series, index) { series.values.sort(function(a, b) return a[0] - b[0];});});. But still it is not working. I am relatively new to these, could you please correct the mistake in my above sorting or direct me to some ref material for me to work on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how Angular works. From a NVD3 point of view it needs to look like the following, replace `y` with your sorted timestamps. Try to pass a sorted data structure into the chart.

Try this sample dataset structure :

```
[
  {
    "key": "Stream0",
    "values": [
      {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 1.7295799731844639,
        "series": 0
      },
      {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 1.4786744584068263,
        "series": 0
      },
      {
        "x": 2,
        "y": 1.2933604184307024,
        "series": 0
      },
      {
        "x": 3,
        "y": 1.0545169052395873,
        "series": 0
      },
      {
        "x": 4,
        "y": 0.9355866365151941,
        "series": 0
      },
      {
        "x": 5,
        "y": 0.7635212444141124,
        "series": 0
      },
      {
        "x": 6,
        "y": 0.565136089920293,
        "series": 0
      },
      {
        "x": 7,
        "y": 0.53905008125296,
        "series": 0
      },
      {
        "x": 8,
        "y": 0.37174374881238753,
        "series": 0
      },
      {
        "x": 9,
        "y": 0.34531043658548377,
        "series": 0
      },
      {
        "x": 10,
        "y": 0.328211247181182,
        "series": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Stream1",
    "values": [
      {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0.13249877834306772,
        "series": 1
      },
      {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 0.18966416588140741,
        "series": 1
      },
      {
        "x": 2,
        "y": 0.15503209036373955,
        "series": 1
      },
      {
        "x": 3,
        "y": 0.16519284756400573,
        "series": 1
      },
      {
        "x": 4,
        "y": 0.19680925364034846,
        "series": 1
      },
      {
        "x": 5,
        "y": 0.15990817677876387,
        "series": 1
      },
      {
        "x": 6,
        "y": 0.19427819689638404,
        "series": 1
      },
      {
        "x": 7,
        "y": 0.14638497347498736,
        "series": 1
      },
      {
        "x": 8,
        "y": 0.252980017823181,
        "series": 1
      },
      {
        "x": 9,
        "y": 0.38707426684750496,
        "series": 1
      },
      {
        "x": 10,
        "y": 0.5779972814312548,
        "series": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Stream2",
    "values": [
      {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0.6236632729965124,
        "series": 2
      },
      {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 0.7353256169924149,
        "series": 2
      },
      {
        "x": 2,
        "y": 0.9528230226672629,
        "series": 2
      },
      {
        "x": 3,
        "y": 1.1790902509337027,
        "series": 2
      },
      {
        "x": 4,
        "y": 1.3709431861337658,
        "series": 2
      },
      {
        "x": 5,
        "y": 1.5484649771429377,
        "series": 2
      },
      {
        "x": 6,
        "y": 1.5936007146924656,
        "series": 2
      },
      {
        "x": 7,
        "y": 1.5565281321682678,
        "series": 2
      },
      {
        "x": 8,
        "y": 1.5324611327325905,
        "series": 2
      },
      {
        "x": 9,
        "y": 1.5132696097009746,
        "series": 2
      },
      {
        "x": 10,
        "y": 1.3909548760195327,
        "series": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The following function too fixes the above mentioned chart display problem.

```
angular.forEach($scope.data, function(series, index) {
                            series.values.sort(function(a, b) {
                                return a.x - b.x;
                            });
                        });
```